# How to find alpha and beta for inverse gamma distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I'd like to experiment with using [inverse gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) for my data set.

If my data was distributed normally, I would have to find sigma and median, and I would be all set.

For inverse gamma distribution, I understand that I'll have to find alpha and beta.

How do I do that?

Comment: [Maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article, which answers my question

[Estimating an Inverse Gamma distribution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01019.pdf)